# Custom web fonts won't load using Vuejs

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

Been searching on a fix fir the issue I'm facing right now. Already tried [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/56) but no luck. Also installed [url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader) via npm. After running `npm run dev`, I got no error or warnings but icon doesn't render on the browser.

webpack.base.conf.js

```
{
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
            limit: 100000,
            name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
            publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '../../' : '/'
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000000'`, where the number after limit is larger than your font file

Comment: @Ferrybig, alredy did but got the same.